# multiple files and data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm seeking your mighty knowledge, to make this clear for me cause I can't find a way to make it work.
I have a form where the user can insert `name, email ... and multiple files`, I planned to make two tables, one for the `user information` and second for `the files`, files will be stored in a folder in the server and I'll save their links into the `the files` table.
But I don't know how I can make these two tables connect to each other so I retrieve files' links with their user. I though that I may add a `userId` in `files table` that equals the user's id ... I'm not sure if that is possible or I can make.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible. Its a one to many relationship between user and files .ie User has many File.
A typical table setup would have a primary key 'id' in Users which is also a FK in files.

users 
    id Int
    ..more columns

files
   user_id
    path
    more columns

Inner join Sql to select  user. files .eg

Select *From users  inner join files on users.id = files.user_id;

Comment: and while I'm inserting files' path into the table I should join `files.user_id = users.id` ?

Comment: No you save the user first(if you have nt.) Then you use the user's id as user_id in the files table for any file that belongs to the user.